# How to create or import a bilingual table from Word in LaTeX?

Tags: parallel, parcolumns, gregorio

Short story: How can I recreate [this](https://www.dropbox.com/s/ap85xfeekfau1qh/Snippet.docx?dl=0) table in LaTeX, I am currently experimenting with the `parallel` and `parcolumns` packages, but the results are not similar.

Long story: I am trying to make a bilingual booklet for Gregorian chant, and I have a setup on Word that I like the aesthetic of. But getting proper chant notation is easier with LaTeX, so I would like to recreate [this](https://www.dropbox.com/s/ap85xfeekfau1qh/Snippet.docx?dl=0) table from Word. I am not sure how to proceed as I am completely green when it comes to typesetting.

Edit by me, including my pitiful minimal attempt

```
    \begin{Parallel}[v]{0.4\textwidth}{0.51\textwidth}
\tolerance=1000

\ParallelLText{Examen conscientiæ vel Pater Noster totum secreto}
\ParallelRText{Enten ransager man sin samvittighed eller beder Fader vor i stilhed.}

\ParallelPar
\ParallelLText{Pater noster, qui es in cælis, sanctificétur nomen tuum: advéniat regnum tuum: fiat volúntas tua, sicut in cælo et in terra. Panem nostrum quotidiánum da nobis hódie: et dimítte nobis débita nostra, sicut et nos dimíttimus debitóribus nostris: et ne nos indúcas in tentatiónem: sed líbera nos a malo. Amen.}
\ParallelRText{Fader vor, du som er i Himlen. Helliget vorde dit navn, komme dit rige. Ske din vilje, som i Himlen så og på jorden. Giv os i dag vort daglige brød og forlad os vor skyld, som og vi forlader vore skyldnere, og led os ikke i fristelse, men frels os fra det onde. Amen.}  


\end{Parallel}
```

---

Edit by naph: embedded image of example.

[image]

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SX! Rather than posting external links it is better to post the file, or a screen shot, because external links may disappear in the future, which will mean that your question will be almost useless for others. It is also good to post a [minimal working example](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/questions/228) and to show us what you have tried. People are more likely to help you if you supply compliable code to start from and if you show that you have at least tried to help yourself.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here's something for you to start with:

[image]

I made a command `\bilingual` that takes one optional and four mandatory arguments:

```
\bilingual[<color>]{<title a>}{<text a>}{<title b>}{<text b>}
```

The command takes care of the coloring and formatting of the text as well as the height of the boxes.

You can change the formatting with the options of the `\bilingbox`, which is responsible for formatting the box itself, and changing the formatting commands of the `\emphfirst` and `\bilingual` macros.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}

\usepackage{xcolor}
\usepackage{microtype}

\usepackage[xparse]{tcolorbox}

\def\emphfirst#1#2#3\@nil{%
  {\Large\color{#1}\bfseries#2}#3
}
\NewTotalTColorBox{\bilingbox}{O{once}+m}{size=fbox,sharp corners,
  colframe=black,colback=white,width=0.49\linewidth,nobeforeafter,
  equal height group=#1}{#2}
\newcount\blcount
\newcommand{\bilingual}[5][red]{%
\global\advance\blcount by 1%
\edef\blname{group\the\blcount}%
\expandafter\bilingbox\expandafter[\blname]{%
  \textit{\color{#1}#2}%
  \medskip\par%
  \emphfirst{#1}#3\@nil%
}%
\expandafter\bilingbox\expandafter[\blname]{%
  \textit{\color{#1}#4}%
  \medskip\par%
  \emphfirst{#1}#5\@nil%
}%
}

\begin{document}

\bilingual{Examen conscienti\ae vel Pater Noster totum secreto.}{%
  Pater noster, qui es in cælis,
  sanctificétur nomen tuum: advéniat regnum tuum: fiat volúntas
  tua, sicut in cælo et in terra. Panem nostrum quotidiánum da
  nobis hódie: et dimítte nobis débita nostra, sicut et nos
  dimíttimus debitóribus nostris: et ne nos indúcas in
  tentatiónem: sed líbera nos a malo. Amen.
}%
{Enten ransager man sin samvittighed eller beder Fader vor i stilhed.}{%
  Fader vor, du som er i Himlen.
  Helliget vorde dit navn, komme dit rige. Ske din vilje, som i
  Himlen så og på jorden. Giv os i dag vort daglige brød og
  forlad os vor skyld, som og vi forlader vore skyldnere, og
  led os ikke i fristelse, men frels os fra det onde. Amen.
}

\end{document}
```