# How can I get the max height of a group boxes in an environment without incrementing a counter?

Tags: tex-core, boxes, counters, dimensions

Here I use three macros `\a`, `\b`, `\c` which are captured into `\BODY`. I measure the height of `\BODY` and set the height `\nodeboxht` register to its result.

This ensure the height of all boxes match the height of the highest box.

Measuing the height of `\BODY` has a negative aspect. If the `\BODY` contains a counter, it will be incremented during the measuring step, then again at the typesetting step. This yields undesired even numbers. I could probably solve this with some `\ifnum` logic, but I am wondering if there is a better way.

## Output

The counter is initialized with 0. The numbers 1, 3, and 5 are invisible, because they are expanded with the first `\BODY` call for measuring purposes.

## My Solution

Using a global TeX register (LaTeX counter), I can just use it as a TRUE / FALSE indicator. This is totally a hack job.

```
\newcount\counterTF% TeX Register init
\global\counterTF=0\relax% TeX Counter Definition Equivalent of LaTeX

% Redefine with logic such that it only steps and uses counter every other call
\gdef\typesetcounter{\ifnum0=\counterTF\relax\global\counterTF=1\else\stepcounter{boxcount}\arabic{boxcount}\global\counterTF=0\fi}
```

[image]

## Code

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{fontspec}% xelatex
\usepackage{environ}
\usepackage{tikz}

% Plain TeX Box for Reference
%\newbox\mybox
%\setbox\mybox=\hbox{Hello}
%\showthe\wd\mybox
%\bye

% LaTeX Wrapper for TeX Box for Reference
%\newsavebox{\mybox}
%\savebox{\mybox}{\parbox{4cm}{\lorem}}
%\showthe\wd\mybox 

\makeatletter % make @ cat code 11

% Initialize Registers
\newcounter{boxcount}
\setcounter{boxcount}{0}
\gdef\typesetcounter{\stepcounter{boxcount}\arabic{boxcount}}

 % Define Row Environment (using environ package for \BODY)
\NewEnviron{row}{%
  \par\noindent\ignorespaces%
  \sbox\@tempboxa{\BODY}% save contents of environment (contains all boxes)
  \nodeboxht=\the\ht\@tempboxa% measure height of \BODY, which implies box with max height
  \BODY% typeset body
  \ignorespacesafterend%
}

% Define Node Box Formatting
\long\def\nodebox#1#2#3{\tikz \node [outer sep=0pt,draw, minimum width=#1,minimum height=#2, align=center] {#3};}

% Initialize Node Height Dimension
\newdimen\nodeboxht
\nodeboxht=\dimexpr2\fontcharht\font`|\relax% set to height of a strut

% Define Node Boxes to Fill Row
\def\a{\nodebox{2cm}{\nodeboxht}{\typesetcounter.\quad abc}}
\def\b{\nodebox{3cm}{\nodeboxht}{def}}
\def\c{\nodebox{1cm}{\nodeboxht}{ghi\\anotherline\\anotherline}}

\makeatother % make @ cat code 9

\begin{document}
\begin{row}% Desired Row Number: 1
\a{}%
\b{}%
\c{}%
\end{row}
\begin{row}% Desired Row Number: 2
\a{}%
\b{}%
\c{}%
\end{row}
\begin{row}% Desired Row Number: 3
\a{}%
\b{}%
\c{}%
\end{row}
\end{document}
```

## Related

- [How can I dynamically set the box height to the max height of a group of boxes?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/428462/how-can-i-dynamically-set-the-box-height-to-the-max-height-of-a-group-of-boxes)

Comment: After your `\sbox` invocation, you could issue a `\addtocounter{boxcount}{-1}`.  However, I don't know if this fixes your more general cases (not shown in your MWE).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here, I redefine `\typesetcounter` to `\relax` before doing the `\sbox` (which is only used for vertical measurement).  After the `\sbox` is set, I redefine `\typesetcounter` to what you want it to be (incrementing and typesetting the counter).

```
\documentclass{article}
%\usepackage{fontspec}% xelatex
\usepackage{environ}
\usepackage{tikz}

% Plain TeX Box for Reference
%\newbox\mybox
%\setbox\mybox=\hbox{Hello}
%\showthe\wd\mybox
%\bye

% LaTeX Wrapper for TeX Box for Reference
%\newsavebox{\mybox}
%\savebox{\mybox}{\parbox{4cm}{\lorem}}
%\showthe\wd\mybox 

\makeatletter % make @ cat code 11

% Initialize Registers
\newcounter{boxcount}
\setcounter{boxcount}{0}

 % Define Row Environment (using environ package for \BODY)
\NewEnviron{row}{%
  \par\noindent\ignorespaces%
  \let\typesetcounter\relax
  \sbox\@tempboxa{\BODY}% save contents of environment (contains all boxes)
  \gdef\typesetcounter{\stepcounter{boxcount}\arabic{boxcount}}
  \nodeboxht=\the\ht\@tempboxa% measure height of \BODY, which implies box with max height
  \BODY% typeset body
  \ignorespacesafterend%
}

% Define Node Box Formatting
\long\def\nodebox#1#2#3{\tikz \node [outer sep=0pt,draw, minimum width=#1,minimum height=#2, align=center] {#3};}

% Initialize Node Height Dimension
\newdimen\nodeboxht
\nodeboxht=\dimexpr2\fontcharht\font`|\relax% set to height of a strut

% Define Node Boxes to Fill Row
\def\a{\nodebox{2cm}{\nodeboxht}{\typesetcounter.\quad abc}}
\def\b{\nodebox{3cm}{\nodeboxht}{def}}
\def\c{\nodebox{1cm}{\nodeboxht}{ghi\\anotherline\\anotherline}}

\makeatother % make @ cat code 9

\begin{document}
\begin{row}% Desired Row Number: 1
\a{}%
\b{}%
\c{}%
\end{row}
\begin{row}% Desired Row Number: 2
\a{}%
\b{}%
\c{}%
\end{row}
\begin{row}% Desired Row Number: 3
\a{}%
\b{}%
\c{}%
\end{row}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Nice solution. I forgot to mention that I don't know which counter is in a box, because there are *n* known counters (in the real thing, not in my minimal example). However, using your method, there should be no harm in setting all counters to `\relax` and restoring them, regardless of whether or not they are used in a box.

Comment: @JonathanKomar That is exactly right, at least they way I envisioned it.